# Debugging with IIS requires deleted reference

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7, iis-express

Windows Ent 7, SP1
IIS 7.5
Visual Studio 2013

My task has been to get rid of a third party dependency within a web application. I have re-written the necessary code, deleted all of the references to those dlls and uninstalled the 3rd party software. No references in the web.config, the solution, and zero import/using statements in the code...

When I publish the compiled web application (and access via IIS/port 80), it works. When I debug the web application with IIS Express, it works. When I debug the application with IIS, it fails, requiring one of the deleted references.

I have tried creating a new app pool with no luck. I also deleted all of the asp.net temp files. Any idea why IIS is still looking for an old reference/how to make it stop?

Comment: Try clean %TEMP% and temporary ASP.NET files. Sometimes it helps

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did that already.Thanks

Comment: maybe it's still in your GAC, or something that references it is still in your GAC (or elsewhere in the system path)? You could try updating all references in your project to use specific version, and ensure they are pointing to the DLLs that you want them to point to